# building the tdlib project in java

Tags: java, cmake, telegram, tdlib

when i try to build a java project i get the following error:

MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET Framework

```
Generating Java TDLib API source files
  Building Java code
  C:\Users\T\Desktop\t\td\example\java\org\drinkless\tdlib\Client.java:229: warning: [removal] finalize() in Obje
  ct has been deprecated and marked for removal
      protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
                     ^
  1 warning
  Generating Javadoc documentation
  Loading source files for package org.drinkless.tdlib...

CUSTOMBUILD : error : No source files for package org.drinkless.tdlib [C:\Users\T\Desktop\t\td\example\java\build
\generate_javadoc.vcxproj] D:\N\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: custom assembly for "C:\Users\T\Desktop\t\td\example\java\build\CMakeFiles\38a1aee34003018bfa3f2a5c470b9fa0\generate_javadoc.rul
e;C:\Users\T\Desktop\t\td\example\java\CMakeLists.txt" exited with code 2.
 [C:\Users\T\Desktop\t\td
\example\java\build\generate_javadoc.vcxproj]
```

this happens after trying to enter

```
etc\td\example\java\build> cmake --build . --target install
```

Here's a link to the instructions I'm following https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java

I tried a lot of things from what Google gave out, nothing helped

Comment: related: https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/1dec0e203ca8110ea53f57830eb5d890a648d0e0/example/java/CMakeLists.txt#L67 This might(?) be a bug in tdlib's CMake config. I notice that they don't pass [the `-sourcepath` option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc-command.htm#JSJAV-GUID-3051737B-FFF9-45F9-85D1-5F07D6703592:~:text=%2D%2Dsource%2Dpath%20path%20OR%20%2Dsourcepath%20path) in their call to `javadoc`.

Comment: You can additionally [create an issue ticket](https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/new/choose) describing your issue to get more eyes on this problem. If you do so, please [edit] your post to include a link to it so I can subscribe to it as well.

Comment: https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=Java